# Delay loading of Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, performance, google-tag-manager, pagespeed

I want to delay loading of GTM based on these conditions:

- When page DOM is fully ready, then after 2 seconds
- When mouse is moved
- When page is scrolled
- When click event is registered

This way initial page load time will not be slowed down, and PageSpeed scores will go up.

In my initial testing I have tried removing the script tag, and then adding it later in the console. However, initial PageView is not registered. None of the other events is neither. If I add the script while the page is still loading, it seems to work.

Question is: How can I delay GTM and when GTM is loaded, it finds the events in dataLayer and submits theese too?

Answer (score 3):

This was my work around:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
// specifically this line below makes PageView get's properly triggered and fired
script.onload = () => { dataLayer.push({ event: 'gtm.js', 'gtm.start': (new Date()).getTime(), 'gtm.uniqueEventId': 0 }); }
script.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=YOUR-GTM-ID-HERE'

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: It seems this just executes right away and still tiggers the "Remove unused JavaScript" warning at Google Page Speed. Are you wrapping this in a settimeout?

Comment: @insivika check the code here https://constantsolutions.dk/2020/06/delay-loading-of-google-analytics-google-tag-manager-script-for-better-pagespeed-score-and-initial-load/